# Condition one variable in vars_prompt based on another variable from vars_prompt

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook for Cassandra management.
The playbook has three `vars_prompts`:

1. for hosts input
2. for Cassandra tools like `nodetool` or `systemctl`
3. for the commands of either `nodetool` or `systemctl`

Is it possible to validate the second prompt input value (`nodetool` or `systemctl`) in the third prompt and then display the possible commands to be entered?

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Generate Cassandra Reports
  hosts: "{{ target }}"

  vars_prompt:
    - name: target
      prompt: |

        List of available hosts / groups to choose :
        ------------------------------------------

        {{ groups | dict2items | json_query('[?key!=`all` && key!=`ungrouped`]') | items2dict | to_nice_yaml }}
        Input host / group name or press ENTER for defaults >--> 
      default: group1
      private: no
      serial: 1

    - name: tool
      prompt: |

          Input Tool name [ nodetool or systemctl ] or press ENTER for defaults >-->

      default: nodetool
      private: false
      unsafe: true

    - name: command
      prompt: |
        
        Choose the command


                    {%- if  tool   == 'nodetool' -%}
                            Nodetool commands like  :  status , gossipinfo , compactionstats
                    {%-else-%}
                         Systemctl commands like :  status cassandraDB.service , list-machines
                    {%-endif-%}
                    Input command or press ENTER for defaults >-->

      default: status
      private: false
      unsafe: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables used in attribute `prompt` for `vars_prompt` must be defined when the play starts. So as is (i.e. setting all prompts in the same play), what you are trying is not possible. Meanwhile, you can work around the problem as demonstrated in the following example.

Test file structure:

```
.
├── complex_prompt.yml
└── inventories
    └── demo
        └── hosts.yml
```

Given the demo/test inventory `inventories/demo/hosts.yml`

```yaml
group1:
  hosts:
    a:
    b:
    c:

group2:
  hosts:
    d:
    e:
    f:

all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    x:
    y:
    z:
```

The `complex_prompt.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Ask and set global options
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: target
      prompt: |
        
        List of available hosts / groups to choose :
        ------------------------------------------
        {{ groups | ansible.utils.remove_keys(['all', 'ungrouped']) | to_nice_yaml }}
        Input host / group name or press ENTER for defaults >-->
      default: group1
      private: no

    - name: tool
      prompt: |
        
          Input Tool name [ nodetool or systemctl ] or press ENTER for defaults >-->
      default: nodetool
      private: false
      unsafe: true

  tasks:
    - name: Set global choices as facts for all hosts
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        target: "{{ target }}"
        tool: "{{ tool }}"
      run_once: true


- name: Generate Cassandra Reports
  hosts: "{{ hostvars[groups.all.0].target }}"
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: command
      prompt: |
        
        Choose a
        {%- if  hostvars[groups.all.0].tool == 'nodetool' %}
         Nodetool commands like  :  status , gossipinfo , compactionstats
        {% else %}
         Systemctl commands like :  status cassandraDB.service , list-machines
        {% endif -%}
        Input command or press ENTER for defaults >-->
      default: status
      private: false
      unsafe: true

  tasks:
    - name: Debug all options
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - target
        - tool
        - command
```

gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ complex_prompt.yml 

List of available hosts / groups to choose :
------------------------------------------
group1:
- a
- b
- c
group2:
- d
- e
- f

Input host / group name or press ENTER for defaults >-->
 [group1]: group2

Input Tool name [ nodetool or systemctl ] or press ENTER for defaults >-->
 [nodetool]: nodetool

PLAY [Ask and set global options] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Set global choices as facts for all hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [x]

Choose a Nodetool commands like  :  status , gossipinfo , compactionstats
Input command or press ENTER for defaults >-->
 [status]: compactionstats

PLAY [Generate Cassandra Reports] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Debug all options] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [d] => (item=target) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "target",
    "target": "group2"
}
ok: [d] => (item=tool) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "tool",
    "tool": "nodetool"
}
ok: [e] => (item=target) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "target",
    "target": "group2"
}
ok: [d] => (item=command) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "command": "compactionstats",
    "item": "command"
}
ok: [e] => (item=tool) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "tool",
    "tool": "nodetool"
}
ok: [e] => (item=command) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "command": "compactionstats",
    "item": "command"
}
ok: [f] => (item=target) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "target",
    "target": "group2"
}
ok: [f] => (item=tool) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "tool",
    "tool": "nodetool"
}
ok: [f] => (item=command) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "command": "compactionstats",
    "item": "command"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
d                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
e                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
f                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
x                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi.  Your solution is awesome.  That worked well for my requirement. Thank you somuch for your help.